# Build a view frustum from angles

Tags: mathematics, algorithm, frustum

I have 4 angles, left, right, top & bottom. These angles are in degrees. They define the angle between the forward vector and the corresponding side. I am trying to use these to calculate the required values for Perseective Off Centre function found here http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera-projectionMatrix.html
I tried doing
 `(near plane-far plane) * Tan(angle)`
But that didn't give the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to know exactly what you're looking for.  I believe `TOP` in the referenced link here refers to what I call `o` in the diagram below.

[image]

You just need to complete this for every angle.  Keep in mind the **far plane** is measured from `eye` TO the far plane, and so is the Near plane.  Both **near** and **far** should always be **positive** because they measure a distance **from the eye**. So you *don't* do `far plane - near plane` and you definitely don't do `near plane - far plane` (that will always be a large negative value).

Comment: That is a very similar diagram to what I had on paper :). I see what I did wrong. Don't know why I tried 'near - far'.  I'll try it out and let you know if it works. Thank you.